# Why json_value returns null?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am noticing strange behavior of `JSON_VALUE` function, sometimes it returns `null` even though it returns proper value with almost identical data set. Here's an example:

[image: null value]

```
select JSON_VALUE([value],'$.result_serialized_data') as value,  value as orig 
from #tempFromFile
```

Data from which I'm pulling json_value when it is valid:

```
{"id":2321,"bulk_uuid":"08363917-a654-43fe-94ba-1ec75a18caa3","topic_name":"async.magento.catalog.api.productattributerepositoryinterface.save.post","serialized_data":null,"result_serialized_data":"{\"extension_attributes\":{\"is_pagebuilder_enabled\":false},\"is_wysiwyg_enabled\":false,\"is_html_allowed_on_front\":false,\"used_for_sort_by\":false,\"is_filterable\":false,\"is_filterable_in_search\":false,\"is_used_in_grid\":false,\"is_visible_in_grid\":false,\"is_filterable_in_grid\":false,\"position\":0,\"apply_to\":[],\"is_searchable\":\"1\",\"is_visible_in_advanced_search\":\"0\",\"is_comparable\":\"0\",\"is_used_for_promo_rules\":\"0\",\"is_visible_on_front\":\"0\",\"used_in_product_listing\":\"0\",\"is_visible\":true,\"scope\":\"store\",\"attribute_id\":656,\"attribute_code\":\"pr_atr_374\",\"frontend_input\":\"multiselect\",\"entity_type_id\":\"4\",\"is_required\":false,\"options\":[{\"label\":\" \",\"value\":\"\"},{\"label\":\"36-72Vdc\",\"value\":\"9882\"},{\"label\":\"156-417Vdc\",\"value\":\"9883\"},{\"label\":\"24V\",\"value\":\"9884\"},{\"label\":\"120-370Vdc\",\"value\":\"9885\"},{\"label\":\"141-370Vdc\",\"value\":\"9886\"},{\"label\":\"18-72Vdc\",\"value\":\"9887\"},{\"label\":\"254-420Vdc\",\"value\":\"9888\"},{\"label\":\"254-392Vdc\",\"value\":\"9889\"},{\"label\":\"6-50Vdc\",\"value\":\"9890\"},{\"label\":\"142-431Vdc\",\"value\":\"9891\"},{\"label\":\"248-373Vdc\",\"value\":\"9892\"},{\"label\":\"125-373Vdc\",\"value\":\"9893\"},{\"label\":\"28.8-67.2Vdc\",\"value\":\"9894\"},{\"label\":\"22-72Vdc\",\"value\":\"9895\"},{\"label\":\"127-417Vdc\",\"value\":\"9896\"},{\"label\":\"67.2-154Vdc\",\"value\":\"9897\"},{\"label\":\"250-370Vdc\",\"value\":\"9898\"},{\"label\":\"12Vdc\",\"value\":\"9899\"},{\"label\":\"254-780Vdc\",\"value\":\"9900\"},{\"label\":\"21-28Vdc\",\"value\":\"9901\"},{\"label\":\"254-417Vdc\",\"value\":\"9902\"},{\"label\":\"124-370Vdc\",\"value\":\"9903\"},{\"label\":\"19-36Vdc\",\"value\":\"9904\"},{\"label\":\"33.6-67.2Vdc\",\"value\":\"9905\"},{\"label\":\"480-780Vdc\",\"value\":\"9906\"},{\"label\":\"18-75Vdc\",\"value\":\"9907\"},{\"label\":\"48Vdc\",\"value\":\"9908\"},{\"label\":\"18-36Vdc\",\"value\":\"9909\"},{\"label\":\"127-431Vdc\",\"value\":\"9910\"},{\"label\":\"72-144Vdc\",\"value\":\"9911\"},{\"label\":\"9-36Vdc\",\"value\":\"9912\"},{\"label\":\"248-370Vdc\",\"value\":\"9913\"},{\"label\":\"254-747Vdc\",\"value\":\"9914\"},{\"label\":\"127-370Vdc\",\"value\":\"9915\"},{\"label\":\"9-18Vdc\",\"value\":\"9916\"},{\"label\":\"254-431Vdc\",\"value\":\"9917\"},{\"label\":\"9-56Vdc\",\"value\":\"9918\"},{\"label\":\"9.2-18Vdc\",\"value\":\"9919\"},{\"label\":\"18-32Vdc\",\"value\":\"9920\"},{\"label\":\"24Vdc\",\"value\":\"9921\"},{\"label\":\"9-52Vdc\",\"value\":\"9922\"},{\"label\":\"67.2-143Vdc\",\"value\":\"9923\"},{\"label\":\"240-370Vdc\",\"value\":\"9924\"},{\"label\":\"127-392Vdc\",\"value\":\"9925\"},{\"label\":\"16.8-33.6Vdc\",\"value\":\"9926\"},{\"label\":\"254-370Vdc\",\"value\":\"9927\"},{\"label\":\"19-72Vdc\",\"value\":\"9928\"},{\"label\":\"6-36Vdc\",\"value\":\"9929\"},{\"label\":\"12-24Vdc\",\"value\":\"9930\"}],\"is_user_defined\":true,\"default_frontend_label\":\"\\u012e\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\",\"frontend_labels\":[{\"store_id\":1,\"label\":\"\\u012e\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":2,\"label\":\"\\u012e\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":3,\"label\":\"\\u012e\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":4,\"label\":\"\\u012e\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":5,\"label\":\"\\u012e\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":6,\"label\":\"\\u012e\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":7,\"label\":\"\\u012e\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":8,\"label\":\"\\u012e\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":9,\"label\":\"\\u012e\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"}],\"backend_type\":\"varchar\",\"backend_model\":\"Magento\\\\Eav\\\\Model\\\\Entity\\\\Attribute\\\\Backend\\\\ArrayBackend\",\"default_value\":\"9882,9883,9884,9885,9886,9887,9888,9889,9890,9891,9892,9893,9894,9895,9896,9897,9898,9899,9900,9901,9902,9903,9904,9905,9906,9907,9908,9909,9910,9911,9912,9913,9914,9915,9916,9917,9918,9919,9920,9921,9922,9923,9924,9925,9926,9927,9928,9929,9930\",\"is_unique\":\"0\",\"validation_rules\":[]}","status":1,"result_message":"Service execution success Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Repository\\Interceptor::save","error_code":null}
```

Data when it fails:

```
{"id":2322,"bulk_uuid":"08363917-a654-43fe-94ba-1ec75a18caa3","topic_name":"async.magento.catalog.api.productattributerepositoryinterface.save.post","serialized_data":null,"result_serialized_data":"{\"extension_attributes\":{\"is_pagebuilder_enabled\":false},\"is_wysiwyg_enabled\":false,\"is_html_allowed_on_front\":false,\"used_for_sort_by\":false,\"is_filterable\":false,\"is_filterable_in_search\":false,\"is_used_in_grid\":false,\"is_visible_in_grid\":false,\"is_filterable_in_grid\":false,\"position\":0,\"apply_to\":[],\"is_searchable\":\"1\",\"is_visible_in_advanced_search\":\"0\",\"is_comparable\":\"0\",\"is_used_for_promo_rules\":\"0\",\"is_visible_on_front\":\"0\",\"used_in_product_listing\":\"0\",\"is_visible\":true,\"scope\":\"store\",\"attribute_id\":657,\"attribute_code\":\"pr_atr_375\",\"frontend_input\":\"multiselect\",\"entity_type_id\":\"4\",\"is_required\":false,\"options\":[{\"label\":\" \",\"value\":\"\"},{\"label\":\"27.6V, 27.1V\",\"value\":\"9931\"},{\"label\":\"20V\",\"value\":\"9932\"},{\"label\":\"18.5Vdc\",\"value\":\"9933\"},{\"label\":\"0-100Vdc\",\"value\":\"9934\"},{\"label\":\"60V\",\"value\":\"9935\"},{\"label\":\"50-86V\",\"value\":\"9936\"},{\"label\":\"0-60Vdc\",\"value\":\"9937\"},{\"label\":\"28Vdc\",\"value\":\"9938\"},{\"label\":\"19-38V\",\"value\":\"9939\"},{\"label\":\"-12V, 12V\",\"value\":\"9940\"},{\"label\":\"11-23V\",\"value\":\"9941\"},{\"label\":\"5V, 12V\",\"value\":\"9942\"},{\"label\":\"40-58V\",\"value\":\"9943\"},{\"label\":\"11-33V\",\"value\":\"9944\"},{\"label\":\"26-52V\",\"value\":\"9945\"},{\"label\":\"12Vdc\",\"value\":\"9946\"},{\"label\":\"65-115V\",\"value\":\"9947\"},{\"label\":\"8Vdc\",\"value\":\"9948\"},{\"label\":\"14.0Vdc\",\"value\":\"9949\"},{\"label\":\"20-40V\",\"value\":\"9950\"},{\"label\":\"20-34V\",\"value\":\"9951\"},{\"label\":\"3.3V\",\"value\":\"9952\"},{\"label\":\"7.5V\",\"value\":\"9953\"},{\"label\":\"22-54V\",\"value\":\"9954\"},{\"label\":\"22-38V\",\"value\":\"9955\"},{\"label\":\"24-29V\",\"value\":\"9956\"},{\"label\":\"54-107V\",\"value\":\"9957\"},{\"label\":\"Multi\",\"value\":\"9958\"},{\"label\":\"31-36V\",\"value\":\"9959\"},{\"label\":\"27.6V, 27.6V\",\"value\":\"9960\"},{\"label\":\"12-23V\",\"value\":\"9961\"},{\"label\":\"2-32V\",\"value\":\"9962\"},{\"label\":\"2-30V\",\"value\":\"9963\"},{\"label\":\"2x(0-32)Vdc\",\"value\":\"9964\"},{\"label\":\"-12V, 5V, 12V\",\"value\":\"9965\"},{\"label\":\"54-108V\",\"value\":\"9966\"},{\"label\":\"2-12Vdc\",\"value\":\"9967\"},{\"label\":\"-15Vdc, 15Vdc\",\"value\":\"9968\"},{\"label\":\"0-18Vdc\",\"value\":\"9969\"},{\"label\":\"9-36V\",\"value\":\"9970\"},{\"label\":\"16-32V\",\"value\":\"9971\"},{\"label\":\"71-143V\",\"value\":\"9972\"},{\"label\":\"35-72V\",\"value\":\"9973\"},{\"label\":\"3-7Vdc\",\"value\":\"9974\"},{\"label\":\"24-36V\",\"value\":\"9975\"},{\"label\":\"30-50V\",\"value\":\"9976\"},{\"label\":\"48-58V\",\"value\":\"9977\"},{\"label\":\"27.0V\",\"value\":\"9978\"},{\"label\":\"11-36V\",\"value\":\"9979\"},{\"label\":\"42-428V\",\"value\":\"9980\"},{\"label\":\"48V\",\"value\":\"9981\"},{\"label\":\"15-29V\",\"value\":\"9982\"},{\"label\":\"3-12V\",\"value\":\"9983\"},{\"label\":\"6V\",\"value\":\"9984\"},{\"label\":\"19.0Vdc\",\"value\":\"9985\"},{\"label\":\"43-86V\",\"value\":\"9986\"},{\"label\":\"24-48V\",\"value\":\"9987\"},{\"label\":\"3-12Vdc\",\"value\":\"9988\"},{\"label\":\"2.5V\",\"value\":\"9989\"},{\"label\":\"31-62V\",\"value\":\"9990\"},{\"label\":\"6-25V\",\"value\":\"9991\"},{\"label\":\"172-343V\",\"value\":\"9992\"},{\"label\":\"48-95V\",\"value\":\"9993\"},{\"label\":\"50V-100V\",\"value\":\"9994\"},{\"label\":\"27V\",\"value\":\"9995\"},{\"label\":\"230Vac\",\"value\":\"9996\"},{\"label\":\"42V\",\"value\":\"9997\"},{\"label\":\"72-143V\",\"value\":\"9998\"},{\"label\":\"45-80V\",\"value\":\"9999\"},{\"label\":\"2x(0-30)Vdc\",\"value\":\"10000\"},{\"label\":\"107-215V\",\"value\":\"10001\"},{\"label\":\"57-95\",\"value\":\"10002\"},{\"label\":\"4.2V\",\"value\":\"10003\"},{\"label\":\"5V, 13.8V, 13.4V\",\"value\":\"10004\"},{\"label\":\"16.0Vdc\",\"value\":\"10005\"},{\"label\":\"75-150V\",\"value\":\"10006\"},{\"label\":\"12-43V\",\"value\":\"10007\"},{\"label\":\"214-428V\",\"value\":\"10008\"},{\"label\":\"12-48V\",\"value\":\"10009\"},{\"label\":\"107-214V\",\"value\":\"10010\"},{\"label\":\"14-24V\",\"value\":\"10011\"},{\"label\":\"15-143V\",\"value\":\"10012\"},{\"label\":\"21-215V\",\"value\":\"10013\"},{\"label\":\"36V\",\"value\":\"10014\"},{\"label\":\"5V, 24V\",\"value\":\"10015\"},{\"label\":\"25-43V\",\"value\":\"10016\"},{\"label\":\"24Vdc\",\"value\":\"10017\"},{\"label\":\"6V, 12V\",\"value\":\"10018\"},{\"label\":\"9-48V\",\"value\":\"10019\"},{\"label\":\"54V, 53.5V\",\"value\":\"10020\"},{\"label\":\"Triple\",\"value\":\"10021\"},{\"label\":\"29-57V\",\"value\":\"10022\"},{\"label\":\"14.4V\",\"value\":\"10023\"},{\"label\":\"5V, 20V\",\"value\":\"10024\"},{\"label\":\"15-24Vdc\",\"value\":\"10025\"},{\"label\":\"12-86V\",\"value\":\"10026\"},{\"label\":\"30V\",\"value\":\"10027\"},{\"label\":\"18-186V\",\"value\":\"10028\"},{\"label\":\"24V\",\"value\":\"10029\"},{\"label\":\"150-300V\",\"value\":\"10030\"},{\"label\":\"9-18V\",\"value\":\"10031\"},{\"label\":\"137-274V\",\"value\":\"10032\"},{\"label\":\"30-300V\",\"value\":\"10033\"},{\"label\":\"3-45V\",\"value\":\"10034\"},{\"label\":\"13.8V, 13.8V\",\"value\":\"10035\"},{\"label\":\"119-238V\",\"value\":\"10036\"},{\"label\":\"70-108V\",\"value\":\"10037\"},{\"label\":\"9-24V\",\"value\":\"10038\"},{\"label\":\"0-30Vdc\",\"value\":\"10039\"},{\"label\":\"12-24Vdc\",\"value\":\"10040\"},{\"label\":\"8-12V\",\"value\":\"10041\"},{\"label\":\"3.3Vdc\",\"value\":\"10042\"},{\"label\":\"27-56V\",\"value\":\"10043\"},{\"label\":\"7.5Vdc\",\"value\":\"10044\"},{\"label\":\"142-286V\",\"value\":\"10045\"},{\"label\":\"29-58V\",\"value\":\"10046\"},{\"label\":\"54V\",\"value\":\"10047\"},{\"label\":\"13.8V, 13.3V\",\"value\":\"10048\"},{\"label\":\"28-43V\",\"value\":\"10049\"},{\"label\":\"9V\",\"value\":\"10050\"},{\"label\":\"53-107V\",\"value\":\"10051\"},{\"label\":\"2-46V\",\"value\":\"10052\"},{\"label\":\"34-57V\",\"value\":\"10053\"},{\"label\":\"9Vdc\",\"value\":\"10054\"},{\"label\":\"42-72V\",\"value\":\"10055\"},{\"label\":\"18V\",\"value\":\"10056\"},{\"label\":\"4.0V\",\"value\":\"10057\"},{\"label\":\"9.5-20Vdc\",\"value\":\"10058\"},{\"label\":\"1.5-12Vdc\",\"value\":\"10059\"},{\"label\":\"114-228V\",\"value\":\"10060\"},{\"label\":\"0-50Vdc\",\"value\":\"10061\"},{\"label\":\"18Vdc\",\"value\":\"10062\"},{\"label\":\"15V\",\"value\":\"10063\"},{\"label\":\"6V, 12V, 24V\",\"value\":\"10064\"},{\"label\":\"13-130V\",\"value\":\"10065\"},{\"label\":\"12V\",\"value\":\"10066\"},{\"label\":\"3.8V, 2.8V\",\"value\":\"10067\"},{\"label\":\"89-179V\",\"value\":\"10068\"},{\"label\":\"14.5-20Vdc\",\"value\":\"10069\"},{\"label\":\"Quad\",\"value\":\"10070\"},{\"label\":\"84-129V\",\"value\":\"10071\"},{\"label\":\"6-48V\",\"value\":\"10072\"},{\"label\":\"2.5-4.2V\",\"value\":\"10073\"},{\"label\":\"9-93V\",\"value\":\"10074\"},{\"label\":\"16.5Vdc\",\"value\":\"10075\"},{\"label\":\"2-52V\",\"value\":\"10076\"},{\"label\":\"14.85Vdc\",\"value\":\"10077\"},{\"label\":\"16-24V\",\"value\":\"10078\"},{\"label\":\"13.8V, 13.4V\",\"value\":\"10079\"},{\"label\":\"37-55V\",\"value\":\"10080\"},{\"label\":\"13-23V\",\"value\":\"10081\"},{\"label\":\"21-126V\",\"value\":\"10082\"},{\"label\":\"57-95V\",\"value\":\"10083\"},{\"label\":\"53-105V\",\"value\":\"10084\"},{\"label\":\"36Vdc\",\"value\":\"10085\"},{\"label\":\"15Vdc -15Vdc\",\"value\":\"10086\"},{\"label\":\"35-71V\",\"value\":\"10087\"},{\"label\":\"-12Vdc, 12Vdc\",\"value\":\"10088\"},{\"label\":\"0.5-10V\",\"value\":\"10089\"},{\"label\":\"27.6V, 26.5V\",\"value\":\"10090\"},{\"label\":\"Dual\",\"value\":\"10091\"},{\"label\":\"2.7V\",\"value\":\"10092\"},{\"label\":\"36-72V\",\"value\":\"10093\"},{\"label\":\"5-11V\",\"value\":\"10094\"},{\"label\":\"19.5Vdc\",\"value\":\"10095\"},{\"label\":\"5Vdc\",\"value\":\"10096\"},{\"label\":\"27-54V\",\"value\":\"10097\"},{\"label\":\"6-15Vdc\",\"value\":\"10098\"},{\"label\":\"95-190V\",\"value\":\"10099\"},{\"label\":\"16V\",\"value\":\"10100\"},{\"label\":\"12Vdc -12Vdc\",\"value\":\"10101\"},{\"label\":\"38-64V\",\"value\":\"10102\"},{\"label\":\"167-257V\",\"value\":\"10103\"},{\"label\":\"215-430V\",\"value\":\"10104\"},{\"label\":\"28-100V\",\"value\":\"10105\"},{\"label\":\"19-20Vdc\",\"value\":\"10106\"},{\"label\":\"19Vdc\",\"value\":\"10107\"},{\"label\":\"40-80V\",\"value\":\"10108\"},{\"label\":\"2x(0-50)Vdc\",\"value\":\"10109\"},{\"label\":\"12-16V\",\"value\":\"10110\"},{\"label\":\"15-50V\",\"value\":\"10111\"},{\"label\":\"20Vdc\",\"value\":\"10112\"},{\"label\":\"2-42V\",\"value\":\"10113\"},{\"label\":\"12-22Vdc\",\"value\":\"10114\"},{\"label\":\"3-8.4Vdc\",\"value\":\"10115\"},{\"label\":\"5V, 12V, 24V\",\"value\":\"10116\"},{\"label\":\"0-300Vdc\",\"value\":\"10117\"},{\"label\":\"12-64V\",\"value\":\"10118\"},{\"label\":\"9-42V\",\"value\":\"10119\"},{\"label\":\"143-286V\",\"value\":\"10120\"},{\"label\":\"48-96V\",\"value\":\"10121\"},{\"label\":\"13.5V\",\"value\":\"10122\"},{\"label\":\"8-16V\",\"value\":\"10123\"},{\"label\":\"25-70V\",\"value\":\"10124\"},{\"label\":\"5V\",\"value\":\"10125\"},{\"label\":\"-15V, 5V, 15V\",\"value\":\"10126\"},{\"label\":\"2x(0-60)Vdc\",\"value\":\"10127\"},{\"label\":\"27.6V\",\"value\":\"10128\"},{\"label\":\"26-43V\",\"value\":\"10129\"},{\"label\":\"13.8V\",\"value\":\"10130\"},{\"label\":\"9-30V\",\"value\":\"10131\"},{\"label\":\"9-34V\",\"value\":\"10132\"},{\"label\":\"100-200V\",\"value\":\"10133\"},{\"label\":\"3-30V\",\"value\":\"10134\"},{\"label\":\"48Vdc\",\"value\":\"10135\"},{\"label\":\"5V, 27.6V, 26.5V\",\"value\":\"10136\"},{\"label\":\"15Vdc\",\"value\":\"10137\"}],\"is_user_defined\":true,\"default_frontend_label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\",\"frontend_labels\":[{\"store_id\":1,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":2,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":3,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":4,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":5,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":6,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":7,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":8,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":9,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"}],\"backend_type\":\"varchar\",\"backend_model\":\"Magento\\\\Eav\\\\Model\\\\Entity\\\\Attribute\\\\Backend\\\\ArrayBackend\",\"default_value\":\"9931,9932,9933,9934,9935,9936,9937,9938,9939,9940,9941,9942,9943,9944,9945,9946,9947,9948,9949,9950,9951,9952,9953,9954,9955,9956,9957,9958,9959,9960,9961,9962,9963,9964,9965,9966,9967,9968,9969,9970,9971,9972,9973,9974,9975,9976,9977,9978,9979,9980,9981,9982,9983,9984,9985,9986,9987,9988,9989,9990,9991,9992,9993,9994,9995,9996,9997,9998,9999,10000,10001,10002,10003,10004,10005,10006,10007,10008,10009,10010,10011,10012,10013,10014,10015,10016,10017,10018,10019,10020,10021,10022,10023,10024,10025,10026,10027,10028,10029,10030,10031,10032,10033,10034,10035,10036,10037,10038,10039,10040,10041,10042,10043,10044,10045,10046,10047,10048,10049,10050,10051,10052,10053,10054,10055,10056,10057,10058,10059,10060,10061,10062,10063,10064,10065,10066,10067,10068,10069,10070,10071,10072,10073,10074,10075,10076,10077,10078,10079,10080,10081,10082,10083,10084,10085,10086,10087,10088,10089,10090,10091,10092,10093,10094,10095,10096,10097,10098,10099,10100,10101,10102,10103,10104,10105,10106,10107,10108,10109,10110,10111,10112,10113,10114,10115,10116,10117,10118,10119,10120,10121,10122,10123,10124,10125,10126,10127,10128,10129,10130,10131,10132,10133,10134,10135,10136,10137\",\"is_unique\":\"0\",\"validation_rules\":[]}","status":1,"result_message":"Service execution success Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Repository\\Interceptor::save","error_code":null}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks your value is greater than `4000` characters which is why `JSON_VALUE` gives null.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says if the value is greater than 4000 characters:

- In lax mode, JSON_VALUE returns null.
- In strict mode, JSON_VALUE returns an error.

Try `OPENJSON` for this

```
SELECT j.[value] AS value, 
       t.value   AS orig 
FROM   #tempfromfile t 
       CROSS apply OPENJSON(t.value) j 
WHERE  j.[key] = 'result_serialized_data'
```

Comment: if you run in strict mode `JSON_VALUE([value],'strict $.result_serialized_data')`, you gonna see the error.

Answer (score 1):

As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value), *if the value is greater than 4000 characters, JSON_VALUE() returns null in lax mode and an error in strict mode*. You need to use `OPENJSON()` (with default or explicit schema) instead, because the value for the `result_serialized_data` key in the second JSON string is greater than 4000 characters.

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "id":2322,
    "bulk_uuid":"08363917-a654-43fe-94ba-1ec75a18caa3",
    "topic_name":"async.magento.catalog.api.productattributerepositoryinterface.save.post",
    "serialized_data":null,
    "result_serialized_data":"{\"extension_attributes\":{\"is_pagebuilder_enabled\":false},\"is_wysiwyg_enabled\":false,\"is_html_allowed_on_front\":false,\"used_for_sort_by\":false,\"is_filterable\":false,\"is_filterable_in_search\":false,\"is_used_in_grid\":false,\"is_visible_in_grid\":false,\"is_filterable_in_grid\":false,\"position\":0,\"apply_to\":[],\"is_searchable\":\"1\",\"is_visible_in_advanced_search\":\"0\",\"is_comparable\":\"0\",\"is_used_for_promo_rules\":\"0\",\"is_visible_on_front\":\"0\",\"used_in_product_listing\":\"0\",\"is_visible\":true,\"scope\":\"store\",\"attribute_id\":657,\"attribute_code\":\"pr_atr_375\",\"frontend_input\":\"multiselect\",\"entity_type_id\":\"4\",\"is_required\":false,\"options\":[{\"label\":\" \",\"value\":\"\"},{\"label\":\"27.6V, 27.1V\",\"value\":\"9931\"},{\"label\":\"20V\",\"value\":\"9932\"},{\"label\":\"18.5Vdc\",\"value\":\"9933\"},{\"label\":\"0-100Vdc\",\"value\":\"9934\"},{\"label\":\"60V\",\"value\":\"9935\"},{\"label\":\"50-86V\",\"value\":\"9936\"},{\"label\":\"0-60Vdc\",\"value\":\"9937\"},{\"label\":\"28Vdc\",\"value\":\"9938\"},{\"label\":\"19-38V\",\"value\":\"9939\"},{\"label\":\"-12V, 12V\",\"value\":\"9940\"},{\"label\":\"11-23V\",\"value\":\"9941\"},{\"label\":\"5V, 12V\",\"value\":\"9942\"},{\"label\":\"40-58V\",\"value\":\"9943\"},{\"label\":\"11-33V\",\"value\":\"9944\"},{\"label\":\"26-52V\",\"value\":\"9945\"},{\"label\":\"12Vdc\",\"value\":\"9946\"},{\"label\":\"65-115V\",\"value\":\"9947\"},{\"label\":\"8Vdc\",\"value\":\"9948\"},{\"label\":\"14.0Vdc\",\"value\":\"9949\"},{\"label\":\"20-40V\",\"value\":\"9950\"},{\"label\":\"20-34V\",\"value\":\"9951\"},{\"label\":\"3.3V\",\"value\":\"9952\"},{\"label\":\"7.5V\",\"value\":\"9953\"},{\"label\":\"22-54V\",\"value\":\"9954\"},{\"label\":\"22-38V\",\"value\":\"9955\"},{\"label\":\"24-29V\",\"value\":\"9956\"},{\"label\":\"54-107V\",\"value\":\"9957\"},{\"label\":\"Multi\",\"value\":\"9958\"},{\"label\":\"31-36V\",\"value\":\"9959\"},{\"label\":\"27.6V, 27.6V\",\"value\":\"9960\"},{\"label\":\"12-23V\",\"value\":\"9961\"},{\"label\":\"2-32V\",\"value\":\"9962\"},{\"label\":\"2-30V\",\"value\":\"9963\"},{\"label\":\"2x(0-32)Vdc\",\"value\":\"9964\"},{\"label\":\"-12V, 5V, 12V\",\"value\":\"9965\"},{\"label\":\"54-108V\",\"value\":\"9966\"},{\"label\":\"2-12Vdc\",\"value\":\"9967\"},{\"label\":\"-15Vdc, 15Vdc\",\"value\":\"9968\"},{\"label\":\"0-18Vdc\",\"value\":\"9969\"},{\"label\":\"9-36V\",\"value\":\"9970\"},{\"label\":\"16-32V\",\"value\":\"9971\"},{\"label\":\"71-143V\",\"value\":\"9972\"},{\"label\":\"35-72V\",\"value\":\"9973\"},{\"label\":\"3-7Vdc\",\"value\":\"9974\"},{\"label\":\"24-36V\",\"value\":\"9975\"},{\"label\":\"30-50V\",\"value\":\"9976\"},{\"label\":\"48-58V\",\"value\":\"9977\"},{\"label\":\"27.0V\",\"value\":\"9978\"},{\"label\":\"11-36V\",\"value\":\"9979\"},{\"label\":\"42-428V\",\"value\":\"9980\"},{\"label\":\"48V\",\"value\":\"9981\"},{\"label\":\"15-29V\",\"value\":\"9982\"},{\"label\":\"3-12V\",\"value\":\"9983\"},{\"label\":\"6V\",\"value\":\"9984\"},{\"label\":\"19.0Vdc\",\"value\":\"9985\"},{\"label\":\"43-86V\",\"value\":\"9986\"},{\"label\":\"24-48V\",\"value\":\"9987\"},{\"label\":\"3-12Vdc\",\"value\":\"9988\"},{\"label\":\"2.5V\",\"value\":\"9989\"},{\"label\":\"31-62V\",\"value\":\"9990\"},{\"label\":\"6-25V\",\"value\":\"9991\"},{\"label\":\"172-343V\",\"value\":\"9992\"},{\"label\":\"48-95V\",\"value\":\"9993\"},{\"label\":\"50V-100V\",\"value\":\"9994\"},{\"label\":\"27V\",\"value\":\"9995\"},{\"label\":\"230Vac\",\"value\":\"9996\"},{\"label\":\"42V\",\"value\":\"9997\"},{\"label\":\"72-143V\",\"value\":\"9998\"},{\"label\":\"45-80V\",\"value\":\"9999\"},{\"label\":\"2x(0-30)Vdc\",\"value\":\"10000\"},{\"label\":\"107-215V\",\"value\":\"10001\"},{\"label\":\"57-95\",\"value\":\"10002\"},{\"label\":\"4.2V\",\"value\":\"10003\"},{\"label\":\"5V, 13.8V, 13.4V\",\"value\":\"10004\"},{\"label\":\"16.0Vdc\",\"value\":\"10005\"},{\"label\":\"75-150V\",\"value\":\"10006\"},{\"label\":\"12-43V\",\"value\":\"10007\"},{\"label\":\"214-428V\",\"value\":\"10008\"},{\"label\":\"12-48V\",\"value\":\"10009\"},{\"label\":\"107-214V\",\"value\":\"10010\"},{\"label\":\"14-24V\",\"value\":\"10011\"},{\"label\":\"15-143V\",\"value\":\"10012\"},{\"label\":\"21-215V\",\"value\":\"10013\"},{\"label\":\"36V\",\"value\":\"10014\"},{\"label\":\"5V, 24V\",\"value\":\"10015\"},{\"label\":\"25-43V\",\"value\":\"10016\"},{\"label\":\"24Vdc\",\"value\":\"10017\"},{\"label\":\"6V, 12V\",\"value\":\"10018\"},{\"label\":\"9-48V\",\"value\":\"10019\"},{\"label\":\"54V, 53.5V\",\"value\":\"10020\"},{\"label\":\"Triple\",\"value\":\"10021\"},{\"label\":\"29-57V\",\"value\":\"10022\"},{\"label\":\"14.4V\",\"value\":\"10023\"},{\"label\":\"5V, 20V\",\"value\":\"10024\"},{\"label\":\"15-24Vdc\",\"value\":\"10025\"},{\"label\":\"12-86V\",\"value\":\"10026\"},{\"label\":\"30V\",\"value\":\"10027\"},{\"label\":\"18-186V\",\"value\":\"10028\"},{\"label\":\"24V\",\"value\":\"10029\"},{\"label\":\"150-300V\",\"value\":\"10030\"},{\"label\":\"9-18V\",\"value\":\"10031\"},{\"label\":\"137-274V\",\"value\":\"10032\"},{\"label\":\"30-300V\",\"value\":\"10033\"},{\"label\":\"3-45V\",\"value\":\"10034\"},{\"label\":\"13.8V, 13.8V\",\"value\":\"10035\"},{\"label\":\"119-238V\",\"value\":\"10036\"},{\"label\":\"70-108V\",\"value\":\"10037\"},{\"label\":\"9-24V\",\"value\":\"10038\"},{\"label\":\"0-30Vdc\",\"value\":\"10039\"},{\"label\":\"12-24Vdc\",\"value\":\"10040\"},{\"label\":\"8-12V\",\"value\":\"10041\"},{\"label\":\"3.3Vdc\",\"value\":\"10042\"},{\"label\":\"27-56V\",\"value\":\"10043\"},{\"label\":\"7.5Vdc\",\"value\":\"10044\"},{\"label\":\"142-286V\",\"value\":\"10045\"},{\"label\":\"29-58V\",\"value\":\"10046\"},{\"label\":\"54V\",\"value\":\"10047\"},{\"label\":\"13.8V, 13.3V\",\"value\":\"10048\"},{\"label\":\"28-43V\",\"value\":\"10049\"},{\"label\":\"9V\",\"value\":\"10050\"},{\"label\":\"53-107V\",\"value\":\"10051\"},{\"label\":\"2-46V\",\"value\":\"10052\"},{\"label\":\"34-57V\",\"value\":\"10053\"},{\"label\":\"9Vdc\",\"value\":\"10054\"},{\"label\":\"42-72V\",\"value\":\"10055\"},{\"label\":\"18V\",\"value\":\"10056\"},{\"label\":\"4.0V\",\"value\":\"10057\"},{\"label\":\"9.5-20Vdc\",\"value\":\"10058\"},{\"label\":\"1.5-12Vdc\",\"value\":\"10059\"},{\"label\":\"114-228V\",\"value\":\"10060\"},{\"label\":\"0-50Vdc\",\"value\":\"10061\"},{\"label\":\"18Vdc\",\"value\":\"10062\"},{\"label\":\"15V\",\"value\":\"10063\"},{\"label\":\"6V, 12V, 24V\",\"value\":\"10064\"},{\"label\":\"13-130V\",\"value\":\"10065\"},{\"label\":\"12V\",\"value\":\"10066\"},{\"label\":\"3.8V, 2.8V\",\"value\":\"10067\"},{\"label\":\"89-179V\",\"value\":\"10068\"},{\"label\":\"14.5-20Vdc\",\"value\":\"10069\"},{\"label\":\"Quad\",\"value\":\"10070\"},{\"label\":\"84-129V\",\"value\":\"10071\"},{\"label\":\"6-48V\",\"value\":\"10072\"},{\"label\":\"2.5-4.2V\",\"value\":\"10073\"},{\"label\":\"9-93V\",\"value\":\"10074\"},{\"label\":\"16.5Vdc\",\"value\":\"10075\"},{\"label\":\"2-52V\",\"value\":\"10076\"},{\"label\":\"14.85Vdc\",\"value\":\"10077\"},{\"label\":\"16-24V\",\"value\":\"10078\"},{\"label\":\"13.8V, 13.4V\",\"value\":\"10079\"},{\"label\":\"37-55V\",\"value\":\"10080\"},{\"label\":\"13-23V\",\"value\":\"10081\"},{\"label\":\"21-126V\",\"value\":\"10082\"},{\"label\":\"57-95V\",\"value\":\"10083\"},{\"label\":\"53-105V\",\"value\":\"10084\"},{\"label\":\"36Vdc\",\"value\":\"10085\"},{\"label\":\"15Vdc -15Vdc\",\"value\":\"10086\"},{\"label\":\"35-71V\",\"value\":\"10087\"},{\"label\":\"-12Vdc, 12Vdc\",\"value\":\"10088\"},{\"label\":\"0.5-10V\",\"value\":\"10089\"},{\"label\":\"27.6V, 26.5V\",\"value\":\"10090\"},{\"label\":\"Dual\",\"value\":\"10091\"},{\"label\":\"2.7V\",\"value\":\"10092\"},{\"label\":\"36-72V\",\"value\":\"10093\"},{\"label\":\"5-11V\",\"value\":\"10094\"},{\"label\":\"19.5Vdc\",\"value\":\"10095\"},{\"label\":\"5Vdc\",\"value\":\"10096\"},{\"label\":\"27-54V\",\"value\":\"10097\"},{\"label\":\"6-15Vdc\",\"value\":\"10098\"},{\"label\":\"95-190V\",\"value\":\"10099\"},{\"label\":\"16V\",\"value\":\"10100\"},{\"label\":\"12Vdc -12Vdc\",\"value\":\"10101\"},{\"label\":\"38-64V\",\"value\":\"10102\"},{\"label\":\"167-257V\",\"value\":\"10103\"},{\"label\":\"215-430V\",\"value\":\"10104\"},{\"label\":\"28-100V\",\"value\":\"10105\"},{\"label\":\"19-20Vdc\",\"value\":\"10106\"},{\"label\":\"19Vdc\",\"value\":\"10107\"},{\"label\":\"40-80V\",\"value\":\"10108\"},{\"label\":\"2x(0-50)Vdc\",\"value\":\"10109\"},{\"label\":\"12-16V\",\"value\":\"10110\"},{\"label\":\"15-50V\",\"value\":\"10111\"},{\"label\":\"20Vdc\",\"value\":\"10112\"},{\"label\":\"2-42V\",\"value\":\"10113\"},{\"label\":\"12-22Vdc\",\"value\":\"10114\"},{\"label\":\"3-8.4Vdc\",\"value\":\"10115\"},{\"label\":\"5V, 12V, 24V\",\"value\":\"10116\"},{\"label\":\"0-300Vdc\",\"value\":\"10117\"},{\"label\":\"12-64V\",\"value\":\"10118\"},{\"label\":\"9-42V\",\"value\":\"10119\"},{\"label\":\"143-286V\",\"value\":\"10120\"},{\"label\":\"48-96V\",\"value\":\"10121\"},{\"label\":\"13.5V\",\"value\":\"10122\"},{\"label\":\"8-16V\",\"value\":\"10123\"},{\"label\":\"25-70V\",\"value\":\"10124\"},{\"label\":\"5V\",\"value\":\"10125\"},{\"label\":\"-15V, 5V, 15V\",\"value\":\"10126\"},{\"label\":\"2x(0-60)Vdc\",\"value\":\"10127\"},{\"label\":\"27.6V\",\"value\":\"10128\"},{\"label\":\"26-43V\",\"value\":\"10129\"},{\"label\":\"13.8V\",\"value\":\"10130\"},{\"label\":\"9-30V\",\"value\":\"10131\"},{\"label\":\"9-34V\",\"value\":\"10132\"},{\"label\":\"100-200V\",\"value\":\"10133\"},{\"label\":\"3-30V\",\"value\":\"10134\"},{\"label\":\"48Vdc\",\"value\":\"10135\"},{\"label\":\"5V, 27.6V, 26.5V\",\"value\":\"10136\"},{\"label\":\"15Vdc\",\"value\":\"10137\"}],\"is_user_defined\":true,\"default_frontend_label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\",\"frontend_labels\":[{\"store_id\":1,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":2,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":3,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":4,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":5,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":6,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":7,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":8,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"},{\"store_id\":9,\"label\":\"I\\u0161\\u0117jimo \\u012ftampa DC\"}],\"backend_type\":\"varchar\",\"backend_model\":\"Magento\\\\Eav\\\\Model\\\\Entity\\\\Attribute\\\\Backend\\\\ArrayBackend\",\"default_value\":\"9931,9932,9933,9934,9935,9936,9937,9938,9939,9940,9941,9942,9943,9944,9945,9946,9947,9948,9949,9950,9951,9952,9953,9954,9955,9956,9957,9958,9959,9960,9961,9962,9963,9964,9965,9966,9967,9968,9969,9970,9971,9972,9973,9974,9975,9976,9977,9978,9979,9980,9981,9982,9983,9984,9985,9986,9987,9988,9989,9990,9991,9992,9993,9994,9995,9996,9997,9998,9999,10000,10001,10002,10003,10004,10005,10006,10007,10008,10009,10010,10011,10012,10013,10014,10015,10016,10017,10018,10019,10020,10021,10022,10023,10024,10025,10026,10027,10028,10029,10030,10031,10032,10033,10034,10035,10036,10037,10038,10039,10040,10041,10042,10043,10044,10045,10046,10047,10048,10049,10050,10051,10052,10053,10054,10055,10056,10057,10058,10059,10060,10061,10062,10063,10064,10065,10066,10067,10068,10069,10070,10071,10072,10073,10074,10075,10076,10077,10078,10079,10080,10081,10082,10083,10084,10085,10086,10087,10088,10089,10090,10091,10092,10093,10094,10095,10096,10097,10098,10099,10100,10101,10102,10103,10104,10105,10106,10107,10108,10109,10110,10111,10112,10113,10114,10115,10116,10117,10118,10119,10120,10121,10122,10123,10124,10125,10126,10127,10128,10129,10130,10131,10132,10133,10134,10135,10136,10137\",\"is_unique\":\"0\",\"validation_rules\":[]}",
    "status":1,
    "result_message":"Service execution success Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Repository\\Interceptor::save",
    "error_code":null
}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT [value]
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$')
WHERE [key] = 'result_serialized_data'

-- or

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$') WITH (
   result_serialized_data nvarchar(max) '$.result_serialized_data'
)
```